# Convergence of measures in total variation sense

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose we have measures that defined over the set $\{0,1,2,..,C\}$. Let $\{\mathbb{P}_{n,m}\}$ be a sequence of measures.

Suppose that for fixed $n$, $\mathbb{P}_{n,m}$ converges to $\mathbb{P}_n$ in total variation norm as $m$ approaches infinity. Further, for every $m$, $\mathbb{P}_{n,m}$ converges to $\mathbb{P}$ as $n$ approaches infinity in total variation norm. Then is it true that $\mathbb{P}_n$ converges to $\mathbb{P}$ as $n$ approaches infinity in total variation norm? Please give me a hint. I am struck with this for almost a month.

Comment: This seems like it is just a metric space question: you have $x_{n,m} \to x_n$ for every $n$ and $x_{n,m} \to x$ for every $m$. You then ask whether $x_n \to x$. Consider $d(x_n,x) \leq d(x_n,x_{n,m})+d(x_{n,m},x)$. The problem is now to simultaneously take $m$ large enough that the first term is small and also $n$ large enough that the second term is small. The difficulty is that the rate of convergence of $x_{n,m}$ to $x$ as $n$ goes to infinity might depend on $m$. So the problem is easy if $x_{n,m} \to x$ as $n \to \infty$ *uniformly in $m$*. If not, then you have a more serious problem.

Comment: We do not know $x_{n,m}\to x$ as $n\to \infty $ uniformly in $m$.

Comment: Well, then you need to basically "play the game": let $\varepsilon > 0$, can I choose $N(\varepsilon)$ and $M(\varepsilon,N(\varepsilon))$ large enough that $d(x_n,x_{n,m})+d(x_{n,m},x)<\varepsilon$ whenever $n \geq N,m \geq M$? My guess is that the answer is no, without some uniformity hypothesis.

Comment: Suppose convergence happens in weak sense instead of total variation. Is there any hope?